# Django: Capturing data from URL will not work

Tags: python, django

I have the following statement in my URL.py file

```
(r'^confirm/(\d+)/$', confirm)
```

But this URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm/DMo32zPB15
```

Returns this

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm/DMo32zPB15
Using the URLconf defined in BBN.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^login/$
^ajax/login$
^ajax/login/nact/$
^ajax/login/nact/cancel//$
^ajax/login/nact/resend/$
^confirm/(\d+)/$
The current URL, confirm/DMo32zPB15, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Why won't it regognize the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\d+` means one or more *digits*.

`DMo32zPB15` has both digits and letters. Try `r'^confirm/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$'` instead.

More information about regular expressions can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info for your reading pleasure.

Comment: Thanks, my definition of "digits" was too broad. I though it included characters for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Even if the file now reads `(r'^confirm/(\[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', confirm)` it still gives an error.

Comment: Why are you putting a backslash in there? The `\d+` is replaced by the bit I suggested.

Comment: No worries, I wasn't clear. :) I edited things for a bit more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to your other question about `\d+`.  `\d+` matches only digits.  Your URL contains things that are not digits (like letters).  You should take a look at the regex tutorial I linked in my answer to your other question and get a solid grasp of regular expressions before you try to write URL matchers using them.